# Problema al visualizar datos en Datatable usando un Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server

tengo el siguiente problema al querer visualizar datos en la famosa librería de Datatable usando un Store Procedure hecho en SQLServer, el Store Procedure lo utilizo para mostrar mi información en la tabla, el problema es que en la tabla no se están reflejando mis datos, para esto utilizo PHP y AJAX.

Para ver la información en mi Datatable utilizo su API para adjuntar filas secundarias mas conocido como [Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), el siguiente es el código AJAX con el cual construyo mi tabla y sus parámetros:

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Moneda</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.Moneda+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
       
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url" :"../utileria.php",
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "cache": false,
            "data": {
                'param': 1,             
            },
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data" : "OrdenCompra" },        
            { "data" : "TipoMoneda" },           
           
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

Es importante resaltar que mi fila padre contendrá el campo **Orden_Compra** y mi fila hija el campo **Moneda**

El siguiente es mi codigo PHP en donde hago el llamado a mi **Stored Procedure** y a la clase `conectar.php`

**utileria.php**

```
<?php
    
    $param = $_POST['param'];   
    switch($param) {
        case '1':               
                $query = array();
                include 'conectar.php';
                $sql = "{call SPTest(?)}";          
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }   
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                    $record = array(
                        "F.ORDEN"       => utf8_encode ($row['OrdenCompra']), //Orden de compra
                        "F.MONEDA"          => utf8_encode ($row['TipoMoneda']), //Moneda
                       
                    );
                    array_push($query, $record);
                }
                echo json_encode($query);
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);

                return array(
                    "success"=> count($query) > 0 ? true : false,
                    "data"=>$query
                );

            break;
    
    }
    
?>
```

No se porque mi tabla no me muestra datos, pueda ser que tenga algo malo en cualquiera de mis códigos.

Adicional a lo anterior estoy usando `utf8_encode` con el objetivo de codificar una cadena de caracteres que tenemos en ISO-8859-1 en otro string con codificación UTF-8, en pocas palabras estaré usando caracteres especiales.

Si sirve de ayuda para dar una mejor claridad de la pregunta anexo el codigo HTML con el cual genero mi tabla de Datatables.

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="libraries/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/Example.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="libraries/img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <div class="dividir menu">
            <div class="centrar-vertical">
                <img src="libraries/img/logo.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">              
                <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDatatable">  
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Orden de compra</th>                  
                    <th>Moneda</th>                                                
                </tr>              
            </thead>
        </table>        
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

**Actualización:**

Revisando mi navegador me muestra un `alert` indicándome el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional a esto en el Network de mi navegador estoy recibiendo el siguiente mensaje de error al ver el resultado de la respuesta:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07002
            [SQLSTATE] => 07002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
        )

)
```

**Actualización 2:**

A peticion de un usuario que me lo solicito en uno de los comentarios agrego el codigo de procedimiento almacenado.

**SPTest.sql**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTest]

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select VIJ.PURCHID as 'OrdenCompra',       
       F.MONEDA as 'TipoMoneda'

       FROM PP_FACTURAS F
    INNER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE E ON E.DATAAREA = F.DATAAREAID 
    LEFT  JOIN VendInvoiceJour  VIJ ON  VIJ.DATAAREAID = F.DATAAREAID 

END
```

Comment: Creo que debería dividir su pregunta en dos, o bien editar esta y quitar lo relacionado con Datatable. Evidentemente tiene un error del lado del servidor. Ah, y compartir el procedimiento almacenado, o donde sea que esté ocurriendo el error. Slds

Comment: @eniel.rod Gracias por tu comentario, acabo de añadir el código del procedimiento almacenado, revísalo en mi ultima actualización. Saludos.

Comment: La sintaxis de su procedimiento me resulta un poco extraña, hace algún tiempo que no trabajo con SQL Server, igual estoy equivocado. ¿Ese procedimiento funciona al ejecutarlo directamente, en SQL Server Management Studio por ejemplo? Si no, verifique la [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @eniel.rod Es correcto, funciona al ejecutarlo directamente, con eso descarto que funcione de manera correcta y traiga los resultados requeridos.

Comment: Lo primero que debes confirmarnos es si tu SP funciona, ¿la has probado directamente en el SGBD y funciona? Luego, en el código PHP no estás pasando `$param` a la SP, por tanto no va a funcionar... Convendría que corrijas eso y que depures, en la consola de Javascript o de otro modo, el resultado de tu petición Ajax, ¿devuelve los datos esperados y son un json correcto? Sin haber comprobado esas dos cosas es difícil que puedas avanzar hacia una solución del problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Respecto al procedimiento almacenado:**
Genial si funciona ejecutándolo directamente. Ahora, no se si es correcta la forma en la que lo ejecuta desde PHP (`"{call SPTest(?)}"`). El símbolo `?` es para pasar un parámetro, ¡¿cierto?! Y no veo parámetros en la llamada a `sqlsrv_query()` (el tercer argumento de esta función es para pasar parámetros a la consulta SQL), y el procedimiento tampoco tiene parámetros. La consulta debe ser así `$sql = "{call SPTest}";`

**Respecto al Datatable:**
Hay un problema con la estructura de los datos que espera el Datatable. Además, por algún motivo que desconozco los `.` en los nombres de las propiedades están causando problemas también.

Cambie las siguientes líneas en su archivo `utileria.php`

```
//...

$record = array(
    "F_ORDEN" => utf8_encode ($row['OrdenCompra']), 
    "F_MONEDA" => utf8_encode ($row['TipoMoneda'])                   
);

//...

echo json_encode(["data" => $query]);
```

Y en el código JavaScript

```
columns: [
    //...
    { "data" : "F_ORDEN" },        
    { "data" : "F_MONEDA" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sencilla, El mensaje te lo dice claramente Tu JSON no contiene el formato correcto, deberías de ver exactamente que respuesta estas enviando al datatable

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07002
            [SQLSTATE] => 07002
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Campo COUNT err�neo o error de sintaxis
        )

)
```

En particular en esta parte te esta diciendo que tu consulta puede estar mal en el campo COUNT

Primero valida que te este retornando un Json correcto puedes ocupar esta herramienta https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/